# Add row as a column MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following table:

```
date      | name  | grade
-------------------------
2016-10-01| Alan  | 6
2016-10-03| Josh  | 8
2016-10-06| Alan  | 4
2016-10-05| Alan  | 5
2016-10-14| Rosie | 7
```

I need a query that returns a table that looks like this:

```
 name  | grade1 | grade2 | grade3
----------------------------------
 Alan  | 6      | 4      | 5
 Josh  | 8      | NULL   | NULL
 Rosie | 7      | NULL   | NULL
```

So it basically if it finds a name twice or more times, it adds a column and puts the grade there. Is such a thing even possible?

Also, the grades can be up to one trillion, so the solution linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1) does not work. However it's almost impossible for a "name" to have more than 2 or 3 grades.

Comment: Can someone please explain how my question is the same as the linked one?

Comment: If you truly can have a name with over 1 trillion grades then this is impossible in any RDBMS.  You can't have that many columns in a result set.   Outside of MySQL this would be done using a `pivot` or a `dynamic pivot` but with far fewer column possibilities.  In mySQL your limited to max(case...) but that means writing 1 trillion case statements.  which wouldn't be supported.  So what your asking for can't be done UNLESS you're willing  to limit the number of columns returned.

Comment: If you're willing to accept fewer columns, you could use a user variable to assign a row number to each name ordered by the grade and then use a case statement to evaluate each row number putting the grade value in the column 1,2,3,4...etc) allowing you to show X grades, but not 1 trillion for a single name.

Comment: Thanx! I managed to solve it in the end by using ROW_NUMBER() in the end. But thank you for your time anyway, much appreciated!

Comment: row_number() isn't a feature in mySQL... How did you use it? or is this not a mySQL database?